# SQL Azure Continuous Deployment?

Tags: sql-server, azure, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, continuous-deployment

I have a SQL Server hosting a database, running in an Amazon AWS EC2 instance, with 900gb (not using RDS) of data. Continuous deployments involve console apps doing API calls to replicate the AMIs of the instance and associated EBS volumes, pushing MSIs to run unattended changes. If deployment and tests are successful, clients are pointed to the new database. This gives ability to know how changes will affect the real row content. Ops staff do deployments, developers have no hand in production-region management tasks. Visual Studio is not used.

How would something similar be done with SQL-Azure? From an abstract level, the solution needed is a way to fully copy a complete database configuration as well as all schemata with content. The content size is not insignificant so SO questions/answers I have seen so far involving SQL Migrations and etc don't necessarily apply.

All ideas appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can do copy of a database and validate your changes there. Create database [name] as copy of [source db name]

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help.  I would direct you to Azure VMs with SQL Server rather than Azure SQL Database (SQL Azure is the older name).

Thanks Guy